# Assertion error on mininet-test experiment

Tags: python, mininet

My friend and I tried to reproduce this mininet-test experiment: https://github.com/mininet/mininet-tests/tree/master/dctcp

We self created a VM and installed Mininet 2.2 on ubuntu with kernel version 3.18.9, which included dctcp and tcp_probe function.

Since author suggest kernel version 3.0.1 didn't support those function we needed in Mininetnet. We simply changed the some function name in dctcp.py, such as: **add_host** changed to **addHost**, **add_switch** changed to **addSwitch** ,**add_link** changed to **addLink**.

And we also imported some python function we need, such as : **python-matplotlib**, **python-termcolor** and **bwm-ng**.

But we still encounter the following problems when we plotting the graph - cwnd.png.

Are we missing some important lib or any code need to change?

```
    .Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "dctcp.py", line 250, in <module>
        main()
      File "dctcp.py", line 244, in main
        net.stop()
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/net.py", line 514, in stop
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/link.py", line 479, in stop
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/link.py", line 472, in delete
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/link.py", line 199, in delete
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/link.py", line 64, in cmd
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 350, in cmd
      File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 269, in sendCmd
    AssertionError
    s1
    s1-eth1
    s1-eth2
    s1-eth3
    total
    ['tcp-n3-bw100/qlen_s1-eth1.txt']
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well, and found that if you look at: https://github.com/bigswitch/mininet/blob/master/mininet/node.py and in the monitor() function section you will see that this function sets the waiting flag = False.

So the code can be

```
h1.sendCmd(startbackground_service)
h2.cmd(something_else)
h3.cmd(use_h1_service)
.....
#at some point end h1's background service, naturally or unnaturally
h1.monitor() # will check the service, and set waiting=False
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `h1.monitor()` didn't worked in a similar situation on `mininet 2.3.0` so I replaced the `sendCmd()` with `popen()` and then used the `terminate()` function.

Using the example above I changed it to:

```
p1 = h1.popen(startbackground_service)
h2.cmd(something_else)
h3.cmd(use_h1_service)
.....

p1.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to set a flag `waiting` at the end of a `sendCmd()` call, the flag is check to be `False` on every run of the method. It seem to be reset when the result of the command is received.

As the result you can't send a second command until the response of the first is received. This might just be a race condition but IMHO the library should handle that case in a more clever and transparent way.