# Using Timer() inside For loop

Tags: python, multithreading, mininet

I am using mininet emulator. I want to send command to host every 7 seconds. I am using

```
threading.Timer()
```

inside for loop. I need to pass the arguments to the function as variable that changed every iteration in the loop 
like this

```
for ip in ips:
    t =threading.Timer(7, attacker.cmd ,args= ("sudo python SYN-ACK.py %s 192.168.1.100 %d 80",))%(ip,ips[ip])
```

However, this give me this error

```
 t =threading.Timer(7, attacker.cmd ,args= ("sudo python SYN-ACK.py %s 192.168.1.100 %d 80",))%(ip,ips[ip])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: '_Timer' and 'tuple'
```

After trying mentioned solution I got this exception

```
Exception in thread Thread-31:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 355, in cmd
self.sendCmd( *args, **kwargs )
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 272, in 
sendCmd
assert self.shell and not self.waiting
AssertionError
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: what is `ips`??

Comment: @eyllanesc its a dict of ip addresses with ports

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: @eyllanesc python2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the operation % must be inside the tuple,it is also better to separate the tasks so that it is more readable.:

```
for ip, port in ips.items():
    cmd = "sudo python SYN-ACK.py %s 192.168.1.100 %d 80" % (ip, port)
    t =threading.Timer(7, some_print,args= (cmd,))
    t.start()
```

Comment: I tried this. it removed the syntax error, but the host didn't receive cmd

Comment: @M.salameh 
I recommend you change: `SYN-ACK.py` to fullpath: `/path/of/SYN-ACK.py`, also print `cmd` and tell me what you get.

Comment: this the output when printing the cmd    `sudo python ./SYN-ACK.py 192.168.2.175 192.168.1.100 27486 80`

Comment: @M.salameh As the concatenation is correct, the problem is the path of the .py file, and it also eliminates the point: `./SYN-ACK.py` ----> `SYN-ACK.py`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to start the timer. but this throws an exception     `Exception in thread Thread-31:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 355, in cmd
    self.sendCmd( *args, **kwargs )
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/mininet/node.py", line 272, in sendCmd
    assert self.shell and not self.waiting
AssertionError`

Comment: A probable error is that you have not started the thread with start (), I have updated my solution.

Comment: @M.salameh 
please edit your question and place this error message.

Comment: @M.salameh what is attacker.cmd?

Comment: It is a function that sends command to the host. this function from mininet

Comment: @M.salameh I am installing the module, but I recommend you check the following:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191592/assertion-error-on-mininet-test-experiment and https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2015-April/006001.html